# Replace First Occurrence of Word in SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, string, replace

How to remove first occurrence of a word in SqlServer

```
SELECT REPLACE('SELECT SELECT SELECT','SELECT','HELLO')
```

Required output is

```
HELLO SELECT SELECT

    SELECT 'FLAGY FLAGY' = RIGHT('FLAGY FLAGY', Len('FLAGY FLAGY')-5)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use CHARINDEX to find the first occurrence, STUFF to replace, and COALESCE in case the string is not found:

```
DECLARE @input varchar(1000)
SELECT @input='SELECT SELECT SELECT'

SELECT COALESCE(STUFF(@input, CHARINDEX('SELECT', @input), 6, 'HELLO'), @input)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Accepting answers rewards the contributor and helps those that follow you to find the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100) = 'SELECT SELECT SELECT'
DECLARE @word VARCHAR(100) = 'SELECT'
DECLARE @newWord VARCHAR(100) = 'WORD'
SELECT @string, stuff(@string, charindex(@word, @string), len(@word), @newWord)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [stuff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) to overwrite part of a string with another string.  [CharIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186323.aspx) tells you where the first occurance begins.

```
DECLARE @Txt NVARCHAR(255) = 'SELECT SELECT SELECT'

SELECT  
    ISNULL(STUFF(@Txt, CHARINDEX('SELECT', @Txt), LEN('SELECT'), 'HELLO'), @Txt)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(20)
    SET @string = 'SELECT SELECT SELECT'
    SELECT 'HELLO ' + LEFT(@string, LEN(@string) - CHARINDEX(' ',@string))
```